# Ranking of causal models

Tags: causality, method-comparison

I remember seeing a paper that ranked causal statistical models, published by some research body, by quality in terms of generalizability or some similar facet(s). This would be a "hierarchy of evidence" type of list. The models included difference in difference (ranked highly), instrumental variables, and other techniques of exploiting natural experiments, pseudo-randomization, etc.

Obviously, depending on context (assumptions, data availability, academic field), different models are applicable in different situations. With that caveat, the models were ranked, and I would like to find it again to review the argumentation used.

Although I am discussing a specific publication, I am interested in any literature related to general comparisons or rankings of causal statistical models.

Comment: Answers to [this question](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/142212/what-are-the-best-empirical-studies-comparing-causal-inference-with-experimental/) may be relevant.

Comment: The only way I could see some ranking work is based on the plausibility of identification assumptions. However, this is more context based than method based, so unless somebody is ranking methods based on a specific scientific context/subject, I find it very hard to believe the ranking would be meaningful.

Comment: [This article](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2303.16008.pdf) comparing the generalizability of causal measures may be interesting to you.